# Mixing short-circuit operators with other operators

Tags: java, operators

Assume the following expression:

```
public class OperatorTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    if(0 == 0 || ++y == 1) {
        // Some other logic here
    }

    System.out.println(y);
}
```

}

The output is 0. I understand short-circuit operators, in that the right-hand side of || would not execute because the left-hand side evaluates to true. However, ++ takes precedence over short-circuit logical operators, so shouldn't the ++ operator evaluate before the logical operator is evaluated? Note: I probably would not need to do this in the real-world; this is for a certification exam that I'm studying for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short-circuiting logical operators don't even evaluate the right side when short-circuiting.  This is covered by the [JLS, Section 15.24](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24), which covers the `||` operator.

> At run time, the left-hand operand expression is evaluated first; if the result has type `Boolean`, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
>
> If the resulting value is `true`, the value of the conditional-or expression is `true` and the right-hand operand expression is **not evaluated**.

(bold emphasis mine)

So, the `++y` is never evaluated, and `y` remains `0`.

The same short-circuiting behavior exists for the `&&` operator when the left side evaluates to `false`.

Comment: I like the reference to the Java language specification.

Answer (score 0):

The higher precedence operators hold their arguments more closely, as if there were parentheses present.  Your code is equivalent to this:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    if (0 == 0)
    {
        // Some other logic here
    }
    else if (++y == 1)
    {
        // Some other logic here
    }
    System.out.println (y);
}
```